# Deklination von Adjektiven vs Pronomen

Tags: grammar-identification, adjective-ending, indefinite-pronoun

Meines Wissens soll das Wort „einige“ ein Indefinitpronomen sein. Warum wurde dann nicht wie alle anderen Pronomen dekliniert? Es wird nämlich als ein Adjektiv dekliniert und nicht wie ein bestimmter Artikel.

Zum Beispiel:

„Manche jungen Leute“

aber,

„Einige junge Leute“

oder

„Alle jungen Leute“

Gibt es überhaupt irgendeine Regel für die (-n) Endung, nach der man sich orientieren könnte?

Comment: Wikipedia ist ziemlich ausführlich in dem Punkt: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Deklination#Abweichungen_von_den_Grundregeln. Daraus eine nicht nur kopierte Anwort zu generieren überlasse ich aber lieber anderen Experten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man kann nicht erwarten, daß alle Unterschiede zwischen Wörtern sich auf ihre Zugehörigkeit zu einigen wenigen Wortarten zurückführen lassen, insbesondere, da diese  [antiken Ursprungs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part_of_speech#Western%20tradition) sind und selbstverständlich nicht zur Beschreibung des Deutschen gedacht waren.

Indefinites *einig-* verhält sich insofern wie ein Adjektiv, als es keine schwache Flexion an nachfolgenden Adjektiven auslöst. Diese erscheinen vielmehr parallel stark gebeugt.

> einig**e** wenig**e** jung**e** Leute
>   eine Initiative einig**er** wenig**er** jung**er** Leute

Im Gegensatz zu z.B. *viel-, wenig-* kann ihm aber kein Artikelwort vorangehen, es kennt keine schwachen Formen.

> die wenig**en** jung**en** Leute
>   meine wenig**en** echt**en** Freunde
>   *die einig**en** jung**en** Leute
>   *meine einig**en** echt**en** Freunde

Nur, wenn es sich auf ein Zahlwort bezieht, hat *einig-* schwache Formen.

> die einig**en** Hundert Zuschauer

Im Singular findet man Beispiele, in denen es wie ein Artikelwort benutzt wird, also schwache Flexion an nachfolgenden Adjektiven auslöst.

> einiges alt**e** Gerümpel [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/einige)

Die Duden-Grammatik (8. Aufl.) hat unter Randnummer 1526 eine schöne Tabelle, die die Adjektivflexion nach problematischen Artikelwörtern, Adjektiven und Pronomen zusammenfaßt.